# iOS - Use the "upload script "to upload Dsym file in Crashlytics with version 3.14.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

How can I add the [Dsym](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) file using the [upload script](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports-new-sdk) even if I didn't updated the `Crashlytics` version? I have the 3.14.0 version of it so I don't have the `FirebaseCrashlytics` directory in and I just published my app. Now I'm stack because in the `Firebase console` -> `Dsym` screen, it gives me only the way of use the script and not the old way (upload the `Dsym` file from my `Mac` manually).

Right now, I can see few crashes from `Xcode` -> `Organizer` but I'm not sure that all the crashes are tracked in it.

Answer (score 1):

Fabric/Firebaser here - if you're on the legacy Crashlytics SDK, you'll notice that rather than having something like `FirebaseCrashltyics.framework` imported into your app, you should have something like `Crashlytics.framework`. Either one has an upload-symbols script as part of the installation, so use whichever one is supplied as part of the Crashlytics installation. Attaching two screenshots to show the difference.

[legacy Fabric Crashlytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s0Zx.png)

[Firebase Crashlytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTw0i.png)